# How do I serialize a Java object such that it can be deserialized by pickle (Python)?

Tags: java, python, serialization

I'm using a Python service that uses pickled messages as part of its protocol.  I'd like to query this service from Java, but to do so, I need to pickle my message on the client (Java).  Are there any implementations of `pickle` that run on the JVM (ideally with minimal dependencies)?

Clarification: Modifying the server side is not an option, so while alternate serializations would be convenient, they won't solve the problem here.

Comment: Ouch, this is ugly. I don't think so, is there any chance of getting the service to produce JSON or something? Depending on the data served, it may be as simple as swapping `pickle.dumps` for `json.dumps`. The guys behind that service should definitely do that change if it's possible, pickle is a really bad choice for anything apart from prototyping and data that's guaranteed to stay within Python (e.g. because it won't ever matter for anything except your pure-Python application).

Comment: It should be as simple as serializing a Java `Map` into a pickled Python `Hash`.  I don't need to unpickle on the client side.  Pulling in Jython as a dependency is a big pill to swallow though.

Comment: @SethFitzsimmons: Pickle is a Python specific protocol, and it's usually considered 'internal' - the protocol itself isn't documented, and we just use the standard pickle implementations. So unless you want to reimplement the protocol in java, you'll have to depend on Python or Jython.

Comment: @ThomasK: I was hoping someone had already jumped that hurdle after running into a similar "design decision."

Comment: @Seth: I'd really hope such 'design decisions' are rare. JSON is exactly as easy to use from Python.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-javaobj/updates/list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some additional investigation yielded [pyrolite](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite), an MIT-licensed library that allows Java and .NET programs to interface with the Python world.  In addition to remote object functionality, it (more importantly) includes a `pickle` serializer and de-serializer.

Comment: The original link is broken, the current one is `https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java JSON serializer like GSON or Jackson to serilaise quite easily and use a python json pickle to deserialize

Comment: Sure, but in this case I don't have the luxury of modifying the server.