# python pickle.dumps and struct.pack in Java

Tags: java, python, pickle

I'm trying to feed a carbon(Graphite) server with data from a Java application.
I want to use the pickle protocol instead of the oneline protocol because it seems to be much faster.

I've done this in a small python script that a invoke from my Java application. But I want to write this in native Java.

The python script looks like this:

```
listOfMetricTuples = [('test', (1, 1352903620)), ('test', (2, 1352903620))]
payload = pickle.dumps(listOfMetricTuples)
header = struct.pack("!L", len(payload))
message = header + payload
```

It would be great to not need to include any libraries.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: The pickle format is not really used outside Python, and is somewhat complicated (it involves writing a little bytecode VM, as I understand it). I would suggest using a different format (e.g. JSON) to encode your data if possible. Otherwise, it's probably better to find a library that already implements the pickle format than trying to do it yourself.

Comment: I cant change the server. So I must use pickle.dumps. But I found this: http://irmen.home.xs4all.nl/pyrolite/ That I might be able to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its now solved.

I solved it by using Jython and the following code.

```
try{
    Socket s = null;
    try{
    s = new Socket("debian-srv", 2004);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (s == null) {
    return -1;
    }


    PyTuple t = new PyTuple(new PyString("Test.brange-debian.mojo"), new PyTuple(new PyInteger(1352975858), new PyInteger(56)));
    PyTuple t2 = new PyTuple(new PyString("Test.brange-debian.mojo"), new PyTuple(new PyInteger(1352975858-60), new PyInteger(43)));
    PyTuple t3 = new PyTuple(new PyString("Test.brange-debian.mojo"), new PyTuple(new PyInteger(1352975858-2*+60), new PyInteger(65)));

    PyList list = new PyList();
    list.append(t);
    list.append(t2);
    list.append(t3);

    PyString payload = cPickle.dumps(list);

    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(payload.__len__()).array();

    s.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    s.getOutputStream().write(payload.toBytes());
    s.getOutputStream().flush();

    s.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should do some benchmarks to see if that little exercise was worth your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, according to [How do I serialize a Java object such that it can be deserialized by pickle (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558389/how-do-i-serialize-a-java-object-such-that-it-can-be-deserialized-by-pickle-pyt), might be to use  pyrolite. The footprint might be smaller than having to use Jython.